# Algorithms and recurrence

Tags: c++, algorithm

How important is to have the ability to solve recurrences? Would it suffice to have some idea of an upper bound on the worst case running time, maybe just knowing a loose upper bound by looking at the code structure. I mean would it suffice in such case as opposed to solving it exactly?

From a practical standpoint, is this a desired skill in the industry?

Comment: I've never solved a recurrence equation since I left University. It's usually pretty obvious what the algorithmic complexity of some code is just by quickly analysing it. Even that skill isn't particularly important in my experience.

Comment: SO isn't really the place for this, maybe someplace else on stackexchange, like Computer Science?

Comment: @john. If I were designing an algorithm is running time important to keep in mind?

Comment: This question cannot be answered by solving a problem, it is also not related to any technical problem, therefore it does not belong to SO. It would be better to ask on Programmers. It is a place more welcoming to opinion based general questions.

Comment: To provide a link for what @luk32 said - I'd recommend you go to [programmers.se] and ask the question there.  It's a better venue.

Comment: @john You should move that comment to an answer.

Comment: @Comrade Of course, but that wasn't the question you asked.

Comment: @john. I know. It was a follow-up question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion what's important is to have a good idea of how the algorithm will scale: if doubling the input will make the program consume no extra computing resources, if the program will use 2, 4, or 8 times the resources, or even more. It's good to be able to derive a tight upper bound, but in my view it is not essential.

Comment: What if the difference is something like `n^2.91` and `n^3`.

Comment: If you are working on a field where the difference between 2.91 and 3 is important you probably already know how to solve recurrences.